# How remove only scale from transform attribute?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove scale from transform attribute of the following group.

```
<g id="xe_3q1b" transform="translate(142.29928588867188,0) scale(1) "><path id="xe_6bfl" d="M134.16401959993178,165.11582380379258 122.730655342119... " fill="#ff0000" fill-rule="evenodd" pointer-events="bounding-box"></path></g>
```

I have tried

```
var g = getElementsByTagName('g');
g.removeAttribute('scale');
```

Comment: 2 problems, 1 `getElementsByTagName` returns a set of elements not a single one and 2. `scale` isnt an attribute - its part of the value of the `transform` attribute

Comment: Daniel A can u please explain what is e1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `scale(1)` means that there is no scale applied (its 100%) so you might not need removing it in the first place
2. As already mentioned, `scale` is part of `transform` attribute value. In order to remove it you will need to read the value, strip it from it (using regexp, for example) and apply the new value back.